# Blackberry Development & Maven2

Tags: java, maven-2, blackberry, netbeans

I've been exhaustively searching for a way to develop Blackberry apps in Netbeans using Maven2.

Is there anyone here who knows where to get started ? If needs be i'll write the Maven plugin for this myself, but wanted to know whether anyone else has invented that wheel yet.

thanks

Nico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good luck. I've ended up using Eclipse with the JDE extensions from Blackberry, but have implemented all of the build/sign/simulate stuff in Ant, using BB-Ant-Tools.

That allows me to use a CI server running MacOS to build and deploy, and Ant does the heavy lifting of combining appropriate source and assets to build for multiple device and OS versions.

Obviously it's not Maven, but I got an environment where I can build, sign, deploy to a physical device and simulate (only on Windows - the BB simulator is limited in that respect) without having to write too much additional infrastructure.

Comment: yeah. after an exhaustive search i've found openberry but it seems for now we're stuck with Win + eclipse.

Comment: thanks for the ant idea though. i might wrap that in a maven plugin of sorts.

Answer (score -1):

No answer here I'm afraid but there is an eclipse plugin. I mostly commented here so I can be kept up to date with answers.

Comment: yeah, i'm currently working on the Eclipse plugin. However I find the ubuntu + netbeans + maven2 combination just so much better for java development.

Comment: use the star underneath the question voting to keep abreast of updates to this question.   Empty answers like this are discouraged.